# Spring JPA error: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I've got a problem with my Spring web application with JPA and Glassfish server. When I'm trying to add new entry to a database (`entityManager.persist()`), I receive:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
```

Here's my code:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="LibraryPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="service, controller, dao" />


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="LibraryPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library" />
        <property name="username" value="app" />
        <property name="password" value="app" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

UserDao.java

```
package dao;

import entity.User;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Repository("userDao")
@Transactional
public class UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void insert(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if You want to use JTA transaction in your code then

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
```

remove the JpaTransactionManager and replace it with a JTA transaction manager.

Also define the `transacation-type="JTA"` like

```
<persistence-unit name="LibraryPU" transaction-type="JTA">
```

in `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Did it, but got exceptions: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'entityManagerFactory' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager]: Bean property 'entityManagerFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

Comment: When I comment line in dispatcher-servlet.xml: `<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />` the app is deploying but exception `A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()` remains.